# Como substituir dados da tag <script> com jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Estou tentando substituir um determinado valor dentro de um `HTML parseado`, usando a seguinte função eu consigo substituir valores que estão dentro de tags inputs, css e etc:

```
$('input[value="/services/CouponTemplate.mvc/GetCoupon"]').attr('value', function(_, href){
    return "https://meusite.com?url=https://siteremoto.com" + href;
});
```

Só que agora preciso substituir um endereço que está dentro da tag `<script type="text/javascript">`.
Está assim:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var inPlayPreferences={"MarketOrder":,"InPlayAppServiceName":"/services/InPlayApp.mvc/"};</script>
```

Eu preciso substituir o `/services/InPlayApp.mvc/`, eu consigo por PHP com `str_replace`, mas gostaria de saber se tem como fazer o mesmo utilizando jQuery.
Tentei repetir o procedimento trocando o `input` por `script` mas não funcionou, sou iniciante no mundo Javascript.
Existe algo semelhante ao `str_replace` do PHP em jQuery?

Comment: Eu acho que isso deve mesmo ser feito no lado do servidor. Se tens de mudar no lado do cliente é opção simplesmente dar um novo valor à variável?: `inPlayPreferences.InPlayAppServiceName = "/services/novoNome.mvc/";`

Comment: Não entendi o motivo disso. Não poderia apenas atribuir um novo valor ao array? inPlayPreferences["InPlayAppServiceName"] = "novo valor aqui..";

Comment: Os dados de `InPlayAppServiceName` são gerados automaticamente pelo site remoto, se eu atribuísse um novo valor a ele, simplesmente o script pararia de funcionar, pois o código é grande e contém instruções em base_64 que é gerado em cada página de forma diferente, só resumi o código para facilitar a explicação.
Já a questão do Sérgio, eu estou fazendo isso mesmo no lado do servidor, mas queria saber se poderia ser feito no lado cliente, apenas por curiosidade mesmo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode atribuir um identificador para esta tag script, assim fica mais fácil encontrá-la, ex:

```
<script id='scriptQueSeraAlterado' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

#### Com jQuery:

```js
$(function(){
  
  var script = $('#theScript'); // alvo
  var content = 'var bar = 10;'; // conteúdo que será inserido dentro da tag
  
  $('#changeScriptContent').on('click', function(){
    alert('Antes de alterar:\n' + script.get(0).outerHTML);
    script.html(content); // :)
    alert('Depois de alterar:\n' + script.get(0).outerHTML);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script id='theScript'>
    var foo = 2;
</script>

<button id='changeScriptContent'>Alterar</button>
```

#### Somente com Javascript:

```js
var button = document.getElementById('changeScriptContent'), // botão que altera o conteúdo
    script = document.getElementById('theScript'), // alvo
    content = 'var bar = 10;'; // conteúdo que será inserido

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    alert("Antes de alterar:\n" + script.outerHTML);
    script.innerHTML = content; // :)
    alert("Depois de alterar:\n" + script.outerHTML);
});
```

```html
<script id='theScript'>
    var foo = 2;
</script>

<button id='changeScriptContent'>Alterar</button>
```

Comment: Obrigado! excelente.